# Como tratar response erro do Node no React

Tags: node.js, react

Galera comecei react e node a pouco tempo, procurei varias formas de tratar o erro porém não entendo o motivo de não funcionar. Testei o node no isomnia e esta tudo ok, no react eu recebo o o response retornando os dados que preciso, porem nao consigo pegar a mensagem de erro.

authController do Node.js

```
const User = require('../Models/users');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const authConfig = require('../../Config/auth');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mailer = require('../../Modules/mailer');

router.post('/authenticate', async (req, res) => {

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'E-mail nao encontrado ' });
    }

    if (!await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Senha invalida!' });
    }

    user.password = undefined;

    res.send({
        user,
        token: generateToken({ id: user.id }),
    });

});

module.exports = app => app.use('/auth', router);
```

(Coloquei apenas parte do codigo)

ApiService.js do React

```
const ApiService = {

    Login: users => {

        return fetch('http://localhost:8000/auth/authenticate', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }, body: users })
            .then(res => ApiService.TrataErros(res))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => { return res });

    },


    TrataErros: res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error(res.responseText);
        }

        return res;
    }

};

export default ApiService;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentou dar um `console.log(res)` em todo o retorno ao inves de **res.responseText** pra ver se ta vindo algum conteúdo. Caso esteja vindo alguma coisa procura dentro de ***res.data***. Geralmente vem dentro dele.